# Foreign Key table Map

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 Entities that have many combinations on my site.

I would to create the follow hierarchy:

1. Each User have collection of UserRoles.
2. Each UserRole have a fixed collection of PermissionRecords
3. Each PermissionRecord have a fild of PermissionRecordPrivileges that varies from user to user.

I would like to get the user's privileges (getting the permissionRecord and UserRole collection is quite trivial).
As I understand, I need to create a table that merges the following data:
UserId, PermissionRecordId, PermissionPrivilegesId (3 Foreign keys that create primary key)

How can I do this using EF 5 ( or earlier)?

The code:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class User:BaseEntity
{
   public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles{get;set;}
}

public class UserRole:BaseEntity
{
   public ICollection<PermissionRecord> PermissionRecords { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public PermissionRecordPrivileges Privileges { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionRecordPrivileges : BaseEntity
{
    public bool Create { get; set; }

    public bool Read { get; set; }

    public bool Update { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I only see two entities that matter. Are you looking for a ternary relationship?

Comment: Still don't get what you're asking. Do you want everything in one flat table? If so, don't.

Comment: @GertArnold: I edit the question. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology "create a table" is a bit confusing. A table is a database object. I assume you mean a data structure client-side. To collect a `User`'s privileges you can do:

```
var privileges = (from u in context.Users
                 from ur in u.UserRoles
                 from pr in ur.PermissionRecords
                 where u.UserId = id
                 select ur.Privileges).Distinct();
```

where `id` is a variable containing a `User`'s id.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still don't get it - as far as I understand I need to translate the model to object which reflects user's privileges by userId AND userRole. The actual privilege dependes on 3 fields. How can I map 3 object to a on table?

Comment: So you must do `where u.UserId = uid && ur.RoleId = roleId`? (I don't know the property names).

Comment: Just to be sure: I need to create another object which contains the primary keys of tables Users, UserRoles, Permissions and Privileges, where the 3 first foreign keys combination is the new table's primary key. Getting user's privileges is to be done by fetching the value using userId, userRoleId, and permissionId as primaryKey. Am I right?

Comment: Maybe you should add an image of the data model to your question. I don't understand this PermissionRecord entity.

Comment: The fact that my model cannot be clearly described in 3-4 short sentences means that I do something awfully wrong. Please let me reform it and get back to you for further assistance. Sorry for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your **entity model classes** like below.

***Note :*** Need to maintain **Conventions(naming and singular/plural)** when you use **Entity framework Code First**.Like below **:**

**Entity Models**

```
public class UserRole
 {

     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<PermissionRecord> PermissionRecords { get; set; }

 }


public class PermissionRecord 
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual PermissionRecordPrivilege PermissionRecordPrivilege { get; set; }
 }


public class PermissionRecordPrivilege
 {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Create { get; set; }

    public bool Read { get; set; }

    public bool Update { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }

 }
```

Your **Tables** Should like below **:**

**Tables**

```
PermissionRecordPrivileges

Id            int    NotNull
Create        bit   AllowNull
Read          bit   AllowNull
Update        bit   AllowNull
Delete        bit   AllowNull


PermissionRecords

Id                             int    NotNull

PermissionRecordPrivilege_Id   int    NotNull

UserRole_Id                    int    NotNull


UserRoles

Id            int    NotNull
```

*I hope this will help to you.Good Luck.*